# libgdx modelinstance translate 3d objects smoothly over time

Tags: java, eclipse, 3d, libgdx, game-engine

I'm trying to make a 3d character within a top-down view move in the x y directions when the player uses touchDown input.
So far, I have a cube, using LibGDX ModelInstance, moving whenever the screen is touched, but the cube only moves by a set amount of units; what I really want is for the cube to move by that set amount of units over time for however long the player has the touchDown event called.

I have something like this:

```
instance.transform.translate(movementRight);
```

where movementRight is a Vector3(5, 0, 0);
This moves the cube over to the right 5 units once when the player uses the touchDown input. 
How can I hook this up to update every frame? Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a boolean flag that indicates when the cube should be moving right, like this:

```
boolean isMovingRight = false;
```

Set it to **true** in the **touchDown** event, and to **false** in the **touchUp** event.

Then in your render method, do something like this:

```
if(isMovingRight){
    instance.transform.translate(5*delta, 0, 0);
}
```

This will move the instance 5 units per second, it is very important to do it like this,using delta, so It moves at the same speed independant of **FPS**.